# How to replace MSTest by NUnit (C#)

Tags: c#, nunit, mstest

How to replace MSTest with NUnit (C#)?

Answer (score 8):

1. Add nuget package NUnit package into test project

   ```
   Install-Package NUnit
   ```
2. Remove the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
3. Change the following namespace usings from

   ```
   using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
   ```

   to

   ```
   using NUnit.Framework;
   ```
4. Search and replace the following:

   ```
   [TestClass] => [TestFixture]
   [ClassInitialize] => [TestFixtureSetUp]
   [ClassCleanup] => [TestFixtureTearDown]
   [TestInitialize] => [SetUp]
   [TestCleanup] => [TearDown]
   [TestMethod] => [Test]
   Assert.Ignore => Assert.Inconclusive
   ```
5. Unload project, open the .csproj file as Xml and remove line that looks     like:

   ```
   <ProjectTypeGuids>{0b19334d-acce-4bf9-9475-088436fada27};{a9df11a7-84ef-49d2-b13a-9ed7e1f913e6}</ProjectTypeGuids>
   ```
6. Remove (or replace) private or internal modifiers and make sure the Test project has visibility to internal members. You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8) link for `InternalsVisibleTo`.

Comment: This is incomplete. If users use certain features (such as testing private and internal members via MSTest, they have to remove those test cases.

Comment: There's also a good chance that developers might want/need to install the nunit test adapter so they can continue to run tests from within visual studio.

Comment: Good point, but I have ReSharper which contais support for NUnit, so it's not included in my list. What test adapter would you recommend? I can add it as optional step to make this list complete...

Comment: also need to add "NUnit3TestAdapter" package.